# Switching to 2nd screen without using Win+P

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have two screens. Since Screen 1 is faulty, the signal comes to this screen after approximately 10 minutes (when it gets hot). I want to use only Screen 2 using the "Second screen only" option until the signal comes to Screen 1. But when I use the Win+P shortcut, Windows 10 shows the "Project" menu only on Screen 1. So I don't know which option I chose (because no signal on Screen 1 yet). I try to select "Second screen only" option every time by trial and error.

Is there a way to switch to 2nd screen without using Win+P or how is it possible to display the "Project" menu on both screens when using Win+P?

---

<s>This is what I need:</s>

[image]

Don't let the image mislead you. The currently selected option may change. Sometimes 'Duplicate' is selected, sometimes 'Extent', sometimes 'PC screen only'. So I need to know which one is selected to know how many times to press Win+P.

Comment: Physically switch the screens video connectors or the screens. You could also not make screen 1 the faulty screen. Thats easier than changing how Windows works

Comment: Switching the connectors is not an option in my situation. Screen1 (2560x1440) is connected by HDMI, the other (1920x1080) is VGA. I have to use HDMI for Screen1 to get 2560x1440 resolution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need to see the screen :

You could blindly type Win+P, followed by three times down-arrow,
finally pressing Enter.

Using a macro-editor, such as AutoHotKey, you could program
this with one keyboard shortcut.

---

As you say that in your case the Project menu is variable in
order (which is surprising for me), you could use the Windows
[DISPLAYSWITCH command](https://ss64.com/nt/displayswitch.html).

You could use either of :

```
DisplaySwitch 4
DisplaySwitch /external
```

Or perhaps :

```
DisplaySwitch 2
DisplaySwitch /clone
```

AutoHotKey could be programmed to run the command
with one keyboard shortcut.

An example [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
script is:

```
F12::Run, DisplaySwitch 4  ; Switch to the external display only
F11::Run, DisplaySwitch 1  ; Switch to use the primary display only
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: Don't let the image mislead you. The solution you offered would work if the first option was always selected. However, the currently selected option may change. Sometimes 'Duplicate' is selected, sometimes 'Extent', sometimes 'PC screen only'. That's why I asked this question to see which option is selected. So I can know how many times to press Win+P.

Comment: This is surprising, but I added another method to my answer.

Comment: As Kadir Şahbaz has found out pressing Win+P several times actually moves the selection to the next ones.
Using the internal command "DisplaySwitch /external" is a good option, that seems to solve the problem. 
After the 2nd screen is chosen Kadir can go to "More display settings" then click on screen 2, and choose the checkmark "Make this screen my Main".

Comment: No problem - done as requested.